# Draw diagonal line with a specific offset to another diagonal line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, alignment

I have a vertical line with a 45° turn. I want to draw another line next to it with a specific offset. What is the best way to do it?

[image]

I tried moving the pink anchors directly over the orange anchors and then use the move feature to move it -135° with the specific offset.

[image]

But when I move the pink endpoint with `shift` to move it diagonally, it won't snap perfectly to the vertical line.

[image]

In my case, it was off by 0.004 px.

What is a better way to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE. Why not use the offset function?

Comment: @joojaa: But how does that help me with aligning it to the vertical line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object > Path > Offset Path`

[image]

Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) to select and delete unwanted parts of the offset path ....

[image]

Comment: Can I chose parts of a path with that too? I don't want to offset my complete path, only the part with the corner.

Comment: Offset the entire path, then delete what you don't want, as I posted. You can't offset just a portion of the path, but you can **easily** delete things after offsetting.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I could cut the path off before and after the section and after offsetting join them together again.